# How to authorize without Form Data/cookies?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, authorization

I want to authenticate to a website using Python.

I've got a login and password. I've entered my login and an incorrect password to make it easier to find the authorisation request in Network. Only 1 request has appeared. It doesn't contain form data or any information about cookies.

- This is a **screenshot** of this website:

[image: Website screenshot]

- This is my first attempt to authenticate:

[image: First attempt code]

- I've also tried **HTTP authentication**:

```py
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
basic = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')
requests.get('https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/pass', auth=basic)
```

This code has an error too:

```
Max retries exceeded with url: /home/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)')))
```

Comment: Requests can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set verify to False, see the [doc](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)

Comment: I don't think by entering an incorrect login will give you any useful info. You would have to login correctly to get either the cookie (which you could use for further access) or to get the authorization request.